# What does `/usr/local/Cellar/` directory contain?

Tags: macos, folders

I often found software installed under the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/`, such as:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.6
/usr/local/Cellar/minikube/1.23.2
...
```

What's the function of `/usr/local/Cellar/` directory?

whether is `brew` installed softwares is understand it?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by `whether is brew installed softwares is understand it?`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/usr/local/Cellar` is the directory into which Homebrew installs software packages (via `brew install ...`). The relevant files are afterwards linked to from `/usr/local/bin` etc.

Answer (score 7):

Homebrew installs software into `/usr/local/Cellar` by default and then symlinks it to `/usr/local`.

Extensive documentation is available at https://docs.brew.sh/